# How to run code a single time on django channels server startup?

Tags: django, startup, django-channels

Django 1.7+ has `AppConfig.ready` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)), however it seems to be running multiple times with Django Channels. How can I ensure that the code runs exactly once, even with multiple workers? I'm searching for a solution that works both with the dev server and with daphne.

Here is something I want to achieve:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from channels import Channel

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        # if thisIsTheFirstWorker:
        Channel('mychannel').send({
            'text': 'message to be sent only once',
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clean solution, but the following works: make `mychannel` handled by a single worker (use `--exclude-channels=mychannel` on other workers) and create a global variable to check if it's the first invocation of the setup code. It works, since it's the same process.

I'm still looking for a cleaner solution.